# Efficient "real time" retrieval of all docs in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

So I need to be able to get *all* the documents returned by a query from ElasticSearch. The obvious thing to do is to do a scan/scroll series of requests, but there are big warnings all over the docs: **thou shalt not** use scrolls if you expect quick results. And here I actually do need quick results.

So what's the prescribed solution? I can't find any resources on the net except scrolls. Obviously I could just send an enormous `size` parameter with the query, but wouldn't that actually be slower than a scroll request, since it would have to load so much in memory? What's the proper way to do this?

Comment: How many results are we talking about here? Hundreds of thousands, millions, billions? And what do you want to return? Just ids or ids + some fields or entire source? How big is an average records that will be returned by elasticsearch?

Comment: a) thousands. b) a field from each c) not very big. A subdocument with 4 or 5 integer fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we are talking about thousands of small records I would just try to retrieve them all in a single request and see how performance looks like before trying more complicated solutions. Because you are retrieving all records at the same time, you can use [QUERY_AND_FETCH](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-search-type.html#query-and-fetch) search type to speed things up.